# pie de página fijo abajo

Tags: css

estoy tratando de poner un pie de página fijo abajo pero como la tabla es muy pequeña se queda a la mitad. Con las otras tablas no me pasa debido a su tamaño.

```css
.pie{
    position: relative;
 z-index:1030;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0; /* Depende el Ancho de donde se va a colocar */
}
```

```html
<div class="pie">
  <p>&nbsp &nbsp &copy; blalbalala, informática</p>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""> &nbsp </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear un contenedor que abarque el largo total de la web y dentro de el agregarle el footer (ojo, el contenedor con position: relative y el footer con position: absolute)

```css
html,body{
    height: 100%
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.pie{
    background-color: #ededed;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="pie">
      <p>&nbsp &nbsp &copy; blalbalala, informática</p>
      <ul>
        <li><a href=""> &nbsp </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

¿Tal vez estas buscando algo asi? Me chirría el relative:

```
.pie{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Aunque el *positión:absolute* es ir por el buen camino, me temo que tu respuesta no va a funcionar porque depende de muchos factores, como la estructura del resto del HTML. Si el píe es hijo de quien no debe no va a funcionar, ya que el *position:absolute* posiciona dentro del primer padre con *position:relative* que encuentre. Y aunque fuese hijo directo del *body* y este tuviese un *position:relative* cuando se dan estos casos de poco contenido el body, por defecto tiene de altura la suma de las alturas de sus contenidos, por lo que no va a funcionar.